# Run Linux commands from PowerShell

Tags: linux, powershell, automation

I'm able to run below code on Linux to get unmounted disk succesfully.

```bash
alldisks=`/sbin/sfdisk -s | grep -v 'total' | awk -F':' '{print $1}'`
unmounted_disks=""

for disk in $alldisks
do
  /sbin/blkid -o list | grep -q "$disk"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    unmounted_disks="$unmounted_disks $disk"
  fi
done

echo $unmounted_disks
```

But I'm automating this through workbook using PowerShell. I tried below way of sending to Linux after connecting using `New-SSHSession`:

```bsh
**$script** = ('alldisks=`/sbin/sfdisk  -s | grep -v ''total'' | awk -F '':'' ''{print $1}''`
               unmounted_disks=""
               echo $unmounted_disks
               for disk in $alldisks
               do /sbin/blkid -o list | grep -q ''$disk''
               `n
               if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                 then unmounted_disks=''$unmounted_disks $disk''
               fi
               done
               echo $unmounted_disks')
$output = **Invoke-SSHCommand** -Index $session.SessionId **-Command $script** -TimeOut 900 -ErrorAction Stop
```

I get below error:

> bash: -c: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
>   bash: -c: line 8: `               fi '

Comment: get a much easier command to work first, then start adding fancy stuff. I'd also recommend joining the 1990s and use the "modern" form of command-substitution (i.e. `var=$( myCmd)`) instead of back-ticks. Finally, assume that is being processed as one line and separate all cmd sequences with `;` chars.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks shellter. I tried but, bi use. appreciate if you can point out exactly how the command would have looked if you were written.. i mean whole $script variable

Comment: What "workbook"? What are the asterisks in your PowerShell code for?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [here-string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx) for your script:

```
$script = @'
alldisks=`/sbin/sfdisk  -s | grep -v 'total' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'`
unmounted_disks=""
echo $unmounted_disks
for disk in $alldisks
do
  /sbin/blkid -o list | grep -q "$disk"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    unmounted_disks="$unmounted_disks $disk"
  fi
done
echo $unmounted_disks
'@
```